# how to get JSON from woocommerce?

Tags: android, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get JSON from woocommerce for android development.

I want to get all products, newest products, most popular products and Bestselling products.

I want to filter by category too.

I used wp rest api but I don't know how it working exactly.

Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > REST API
Then add key and descriptions u want
Then select user and rest ur permissions for that